# how to Put a img and text middle of a div

Tags: html, css

i have a Div that contain a img and a text
i want to use that Div like a button
here is my html code:

```
 <div id="p6btnBack" class="btn">
            <img id="p6btnCircleBack" src="img/back.png" class="btnCircle" />
            Back
        </div>
```

and css code is :

```
 .btn {
        position: fixed;
        width: 10%;
        top: 24%;
        left: 2%;
        height: 7%;
        font-size: 25pt;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .btnCircle {
        position: relative;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        height:100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

i want to put "Back" text in middle vertical of div ...anybody know how i do taht ?
thx

Comment: Can you post a working JSFiddle code of the problem. I don't understand what you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is :

CSS:

```
.btn{
        position: fixed;
        font-size: 25pt;
        width: 11%;
        top: 83%;
        left: 48%;
        height: 6%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 5%;
    }

    .btnCircle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 3%;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="p6btnBack" class="btn">
        <img id="p6btnCircleBack" src="img/back.png" class="btnCircle" />
        Back
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**css**

write text-align:center; in .btn class

```
btn {
        position: fixed;
        width: 10%;
        top: 24%;
        left: 2%;
        height: 7%;
        font-size: 25pt;
        background-size: cover;
    text-align:center;

    }
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLheLyhs/)**

---

**demo1**
**css**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
    display: table;
}
h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/jrhqh/)**

Comment: you have try jsfiddle?

Comment: yes ... as i sayd your code just put all of elemnt center of div

Comment: i want to put back text middle od vertical

Comment: @combo_ci now you try demo1

Comment: the problem is we have img in div and want back text middle of div